# SwiftUI best way to create base view that will be inherited

Tags: swiftui

I try to find the best way to make a View that will be served like a base view with some default behavior. Here is a example of what I did the best so far:

```
struct BaseView <Content: View>: View{

    @Binding var showSideMenu: Bool

    let view:  () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            view()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth:.infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .offset(x: showSideMenu ? Screen.width / 1.5 : 0)
        .disabled(showSideMenu ? true : false)
        .background(Color.red)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

    }
}
```

```
struct MainView: View {

    @Binding var showSideMenu: Bool

    var body: some View {
        BaseView(showSideMenu: $showSideMenu) {
            VStack{
                Text("HOME")

                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.showSideMenu.toggle()
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Show Menu")
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

What is not good here BaseView must first implement VStack to be like a parent to the other View-s. I want to avoid that or some better solution for a problem.

Comment: This is not inheritance (it is not applicable for Views), but composition... The "better" createria is not specified and not clear, so answer would be rather opinion based. Needed more focus on the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a custom View Modifier. It gets content passed in and you don't need extra stacks:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var showSideMenu: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("HOME")
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.showSideMenu.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                Text("Show Menu")
            }
        }
        .baseViewModifier(showSideMenu: $showSideMenu)
    }
}


extension View {
    func baseViewModifier(showSideMenu: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
        self.modifier(BaseViewModifier(showSideMenu: showSideMenu))
    }
}

struct BaseViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    
    @Binding var showSideMenu: Bool
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        
        content
            .frame(maxWidth:.infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .offset(x: showSideMenu ? UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 1.5 : 0)
            .disabled(showSideMenu ? true : false)
            .background(Color.red)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. It seems to be much better. Thanks